# Download HTML code from element with XPath - Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I need download HTML codes from a element using **XPath**.

**XPath:**

```
//*[@id=":nn"]/div[1]
```

And a picture from element:

[image]

How I can download these HTML codes?

Answer (score 0):

I think by downloading you mean to get the **innerHTML**, if so

```
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':nn']/div[1]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(html)
```

**update  :**

```
import pathlib
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':nn']/div[1]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
pathlib.Path("output.txt").write_text(f"Purchase Amount: {html}")
```

or

```
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=':nn']/div[1]").get_attribute('innerHTML')

file = open("sample.html","w")
file.write(html)
file.close()
```

Comment: Hello, i need download html codes as htmlcodes.html so i don't want print it i need download it.

Comment: @BroImcoolyCoder :  See above, it should work, you should now have a output.text file in your project directory.

Comment: @cruisepandey Hello im getting this error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=':nn']/div[1]"}

Comment: It seems your xpath locator is not working, test the xpath in browser and use, if it's correct then try using explicit wait for the element if it's taking some time to load. The code mentioned above should work.

Comment: @BroImcoolyCoder : Can you share HTML for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the 'innerHTML' attribute after you get the element using the XPath. It would look something like:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=":nn"]/div[1]")`
content = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: How does it different than the other solution ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Hello, how we can download html codes in a .html file?